# xkb is not loading microsoft4000 configuration

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

Maybe I am missing something, but it seems to xkb is not loading microsoft4000 section from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet.

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      microsoft4000
layout:     us
options:    caps:escape
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)+capslock(escape)
geometry:   microsoft(natural)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+capslock(escape)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "microsoft(natural)"    };
};
```

Now, in inet, there is a section from microsoft4000 keyboard

```
// Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "microsoft4000" {
    include "inet(media_nav_common)"
    key <I192>  {       [ XF86Launch1           ]       };
    key <I193>  {       [ XF86Launch2           ]       };
    key <I194>  {       [ XF86Launch3           ]       };
    key <I195>  {       [ XF86Launch4           ]       };
    key <I196>  {       [ XF86Launch5           ]       };
//  Missing because of lack of support from kbd driver: Zoom in and
//  slider.
};
```

But it seems to be ignored. If I monitor keystrokes with xev end press launch keys 1-5, I get following:

```
$ xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
192 XF86Launch5
193 XF86Launch6
194 XF86Launch7
195 XF86Launch8
196 XF86Launch9
```

which should be like XF86Launch1-5? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is, **can you do the things you want to do with these keys?**

Are they always the same keys after rebooting or relogging?  Can you set them as shortcuts (with and without modifiers)?  Whether XKB sees the key as <kbd>XF86Launch1</kbd> or <kbd>XF86Launch5</kbd> is less important than:

- is it consistently that key?
- can you tell *SoftwareX* to *do FunctionY* when that key is pressed? (launch your media player, maximize the current window, or whatever other function you want the key to perform)

---

**Is it a bug?**

- Maybe.  It's certainly not loading the `inet(microsoft4000)` symbols (that's the `microsoft4000` section of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` you quote).  It looks like this could be included from the model definition or as a separate option, but there's no rule for it (in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev*`).  Changing to the `microsoft7000` model may get closer to what you expect.
- ... but probably not.  The exact definition of these keys doesn't really matter -- as long as they're defined as something recognizable, and unique from one another, XKB has done its job.  To that end, your keys appear to be working just fine.  I suspect the `inet(microsoft4000)` symbols date [from 2006-ish](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5783) but were later replaced with the broader `inet(evdev)` section.

You're seeing <kbd>XF86Launch5</kbd> and so on because the `inet(evdev)` section defines these keys:

```
    // Evdev Standardized Keycodes
    partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "evdev" {
        ...
        key <FK14>   {      [ XF86Launch5       ]       };
        key <FK15>   {      [ XF86Launch6       ]       };
        key <FK16>   {      [ XF86Launch7       ]       };
        key <FK17>   {      [ XF86Launch8       ]       };
        key <FK18>   {      [ XF86Launch9       ]       };
    };
```

... and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` confirms they're translated as keycodes `192-196`:

```
    default xkb_keycodes "evdev" {
        ...
        <FK14> = 192;
        <FK15> = 193;
        <FK16> = 194;
        <FK17> = 195;
        <FK18> = 196;
        ...
```

---

**Let's load it anyway!**

First, tell GNOME settings to leave the keyboard alone:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
# change false to true to reenable
```

Then run this for testing:

```
setxkbmap -print | 
  sed -e '/xkb_symbols/s/"[[:space:]]/+inet(microsoft4000)&/' | 
  xkbcomp - $DISPLAY
```

This pipeline dumps your `setxkbmap -print` output, the `sed` adds the `inet(microsoft4000)` definition into the symbols line:

```
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+capslock(escape)+inet(microsoft4000)"    };
```

... which is then piped to `xkbcomp` for compilation and installation into the Xserver.  Now `xev` should show you the `XF86Launch1-5` keys.

If that works, you can make it a permanent change in a couple of ways.

- You can leave the `gsettings` disabled, and add the `setxkbmap ... | sed ... | xkbcomp ...` pipeline to a `$HOME/.xprofile` script that will run at login.  (Alternately, redirect the sed output to `$HOME/.config/my-xkb-map` and you'll only need the `xkbcomp` command at login.)
- You can edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev*` to add the symbols file as an official option.  `evdev` is the option-to-file translation; `evdev.lst` lists a description for each option; `evdev.xml` is an XML version of the descriptions.  I believe you need to get it right in `evdev.xml` for GUI tools to show the new option, but only `evdev.lst` is needed for `setxkbmap` to understand it.  Changes to these system files could be overwritten by future updates, though, so make backups or a `sed` script or a `patch` file to add them back in when necessary.

---

**XKB is great!  Let's make these keys do something else entirely!**

Whoa there, cowboy.  You can certainly [create your own customization](https://superuser.com/a/1168603/685512) if you want.  Copy that `inet(microsoft4000)` symbol clause out to another file and define those keys however you like.  <kbd>F13</kbd>?  <kbd>XF86AudioMicMute</kbd>?

See the resources at the end of that superuser answer for more XKB rabbithole.

Comment: Thanks for such great answer. I had modified xkb to fit my needs but I will try out things you proposed here, once I get more free time. Reason why I asked if it was bug, was that I wanted to make bug report if it is a bug or my error, but I don't understand xkb+udev well enough to be able to tell difference. I find it suspicious to have a section in xkb that is never loaded. If it is not a bug and it it not used, why not simply remove it?

Comment: deprecated software can linger for a long time before it's finally removed.  maybe when the `inet(evdev)` stuff was hooked up as replacement they wanted to leave the old clause in for backwards compatibility; maybe someone forgot to remove it entirely.  as you can see from the `setxkbmap ... | sed ... | xkbcomp ...` pipeline, it's still accessible as-is, even if there's no direct rule for it.  (you can always file a bug on it; they can probably explain the logic behind this change better than i can.)